# Practical Minecraft Rooms

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One of my friends asked recently what sort of practical rooms one should build into their house in Minecraft, and it got me thinking...what ARE the practical rooms one should build for their home base?

Obviously not every room should be directly attached to your main place of operation, but there must be some major conveniences that one should build right onto their house.

So, what are these conveniences, and in what order should a person add them to their home?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting put on hold.  Proper base construction and how to go about it seems like it would be perfectly on-topic.  Maybe a bit broad, but if that's the case I'd like to hear some suggestions on how to narrow this question down before it closes.

Comment: My main issue is that you can have whatever you want in your base. It's Minecraft. That's how the game works, you build whatever you want. There *are* no essentials, per se. I could play the game with a full blown base with every farm, furnace room, etc, or I could FLOB it. It's all up to you.

Comment: I agree with Unionhawk.  Despite answering, I think it is highly subjective, and I hoped to at least hint at such in my answer whilst still trying to be as objective as possible.

Comment: True, but this is less about what you MUST do, and more about what you SHOULD do. I'm not looking for a blueprint to success, more an idea of what a good base ought to contain, and I think that's modular enough to be a question in itself.

Comment: @Zibbobz I believe the issue is the usage of the term "rooms."  Nothing about rooms are necessary in any way - only the contents are, aside from minimal walls themselves.  Dividing things into rooms is entirely for aesthetics only.  It can be reasonably objective to explain what contents you might want, as I have done, but the way you divide and organize it is entirely subjective.

Comment: @Southpaw Hare Ah, you have a point there.  And a list of just everything you might need to survive the game would essentially just be a survival guide.  Still, I feel like there's a question here that's worth answering, I'm just not sure what it ought to be.

Comment: @Zibbobz When you say, "this is less about what you MUST do, and more about what you SHOULD do," I think that's pretty much why it was put on hold as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm definitely going to let this close.  I can't see any way to make it less opinion-based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **primary practical conveniences** that are useful for vanilla Minecraft are:

- Walls, for surviving the night
- A Crafting Table, for all forms of crafting
- A Bed, for sleeping through the night
- Chests, for storing items
- A Furnace, for a great number of utility reasons
- Books, for enchanting

However, **none of these things necessarily require a dedicated room**.  In fact, it is easy to build a single chamber that has all of these things packed into a small room without effort.  Only when you require a large amount of any one of these things, such as dozens of chests or books, might it be required to build dedicated rooms.  At that point, you could subjectively decide that anything en masse would be worthy of its own sectioned area.

Comment: Since the removal of "nightmares" - monsters spawning beside your bed - beds do not necessitate walls, as it is easy to go to bed before monsters start spawning. Just keep an eye on the sun - sleep is possible after the center of the sun is exactly on the horizon / level with player.

Comment: @Orc Wall are useful for security generally when working through the night.

Comment: Crafting Table?

Comment: @Batophobia Ahh, yes.  Of course.

Answer (score 4):

By the time you have an Enchanting Table, you will probably want a room dedicated to enchanting, because of the number of bookshelves you'll want for high-level enchantments. I also find a room for brewing stands and supplies to be helpful when brewing potions en-masse, as I can set up multiple stands and move bottles from one to the other to brew base potion, ingredient, and modifier in an assembly line fashion.

Nether portals can be put in a separate room if you want them indoors, since they spawn pigmen.

Not so much rooms, but outdoors (or indoors depending on your play style), you'll want areas for each of your animals that you plan to breed. You'll want them to be easily accessible but secured from monsters so a creeper won't blow up your entire pig supply.

Depending on your base layout, you might do indoor farming, in which case, that will want to be in a dedicated room. Mushroom farms in particular clamor for their own area, due to the low-light conditions required to grow them.

(Side note: traditional mushroom farms are fairly inefficient; if you want a lot of mushrooms fast, the easier thing to do is to create a large dark room, plant a mushroom in the center, and use bone meal until you get a giant mushroom. Breaking the blocks of the giant mushroom provides lots of mushrooms, which can be used to repeat the process. This requires a room large enough to grow a giant mushroom in, and dark enough for the mushroom to be planted in the first place.)

We play multiplayer and generally share a base between multiple people, so everyone builds their own private area where they can stash their things and a bed, and then we do common areas for storing communal resources. We tend to make a "forge" and a "kitchens", each with multiple furnaces and chests so smelting, crafting, and storage can happen all in the same place. Obviously for single player you'll have less volume of stuff needing to be stored for future use, so you might not need as much specialization.

As far as order, that depends how soon you need each thing. We tend to establish the base, then grow the rooms as our main chests overflow with things. The farming and animals come early, but the enchanting table and brewing stands come late due to the need for diamonds and nether access.

Comment: Farming mushrooms in a natural way is hardly feasible since introduction of giant ones - just save a dozen of bone meal, and you can grow one giant mushroom of each type. Farming giant mushrooms also requires a room, though, due to its space and shade requirements.

Comment: Do giant mushrooms regrow now?  In a way that is practical for harvesting?

Comment: @Zibbobz I added information to my post detailing the process of giant mushroom farming.